# Get text in string between text in said string

Tags: c#, regex, json, string, text

Lets say i have a string that looks like this

```
{
  "_links": {
    "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1/follows/channels?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=25",
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1/follows/channels?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=0"
  },
  "follows": [
    {
      "created_at": "2013-06-02T09:38:45Z",
      "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/test_user1/follows/channels/test_channel"
      },
      "channel": {
        "banner": null,
        "_id": 1,
        "url": "http://www.twitch.tv/test_channel",
        "mature": null,
        "teams": [

        ],
        "status": null,
        "logo": null,
        "name": "test_channel",
        "video_banner": null,
        "display_name": "test_channel",
        "created_at": "2007-05-22T10:37:47Z",
        "delay": 0,
        "game": null,
        "_links": {
          "stream_key": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel/stream_key",
          "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel",
          "videos": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel/videos",
          "commercial": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel/commercial",
          "chat": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/test_channel",
          "features": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel/features"
        },
        "updated_at": "2008-02-12T06:04:29Z",
        "background": null
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The part in channel is gonna appear x amount of times with the "name" part having a different value. How would I, using regex or not get the value in "name" that in the code above has a value of "test_channel". All times that it appears and then print it to a textbox

The only part I think I've managed is the regex part

```
string regex = @"(""name"":)\s+(\w+)(,""video_banner"")";
```

Comment: It is json. Use a json parser instead of regex.

Comment: You're looking for the advice on how to use this regex to find matches in the text string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and [this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Krysvac.RootObject>(yourJsonString);
foreach(var item in obj.follows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.channel.name);
}
```

---

```
public class Krysvac
{
    public class Links
    {
        public string next { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links2
    {
        public string self { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links3
    {
        public string stream_key { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
        public string videos { get; set; }
        public string commercial { get; set; }
        public string chat { get; set; }
        public string features { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channel
    {
        public object banner { get; set; }
        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public object mature { get; set; }
        public List<object> teams { get; set; }
        public object status { get; set; }
        public object logo { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object video_banner { get; set; }
        public string display_name { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public int delay { get; set; }
        public object game { get; set; }
        public Links3 _links { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public object background { get; set; }
    }

    public class Follow
    {
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public Links2 _links { get; set; }
        public Channel channel { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public List<Follow> follows { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to declare these classes, you can use `dynamic` keyword too

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonString);
foreach(var item in obj.follows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.channel.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build classes for your input string like the following using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com), you'll get the following classes:

```
public class Links
{
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
}

public class Links2
{
    public string self { get; set; }
}

public class Links3
{
    public string stream_key { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string videos { get; set; }
    public string commercial { get; set; }
    public string chat { get; set; }
    public string features { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
    public object banner { get; set; }
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public object mature { get; set; }
    public List<object> teams { get; set; }
    public object status { get; set; }
    public object logo { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object video_banner { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public object game { get; set; }
    public Links3 _links { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public object background { get; set; }
}

public class Follow
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public Links2 _links { get; set; }
    public Channel channel { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Links _links { get; set; }
    public List<Follow> follows { get; set; }
}
```

Now you just have to deserialize the input json string to `RootObject` class and fetch all the `name`s in the input string using another utility called [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm)

```
string json = "JSON STRING";
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
List<string> names = root.follows.Select(follow => follow.channel.name).ToList();

foreach ( string name in names )
{
    txtBox += name + "; ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i solved it thanks to the post by L.B

Comment: then you may at least cast an upvote if it works ;) ! Thanks!

Comment: Well i need 15 reputation for that, and i dont have it

Comment: sorry for that! I have upvoted your question, so now you have +5 !

Comment: **a)** I intented `class` not namespace. So it was correct. Please post it as comment instead of editing it. **b)** `root.follows.Select(...)` returns `IEnumerable<string>` not `List<string>`. Adding a `ToList()` is enough but seems like you haven't tested your code before posting. **c)** What is the point in repeating my answer after ~40 minutes?

Comment: I've got a weird problem with the code you, L.B wrote, in 1 case it returns 6 names when it's 100+ names and in another case it returns 25 out of 31. I have no idea why

Comment: @Krysvac then post your **real** json, along with the expected number.

Comment: I answered my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i got it working now, however, if i use my username to get back json, i get a huge piece of code that you can view here: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/krysvac/follows/channels

I folllow 31 people but when i use my program on it with the code

```
using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                string json_data = w.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + input + "/follows/channels");

                dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_data);
                foreach (var item in obj.follows)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(item.channel.name.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);                                       
                }
            }
```

i get 25 out of my 31 people back in the textbox and i dont know why, i tried it on a person that should return more than 100 and got 6 people back.

Comment: Your API returns 25 results, to get the next results use `(int)obj._total` and `obj._links.next` which is `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/krysvac/follows/channels?direction=DESC&limit=25&offset=25`

Comment: I'm still a beginner at c# so forgive me when i ask for clarification on what you mean

Comment: You API returns the results in *chunks* (25 items per request). Using the `(int)obj._total` you should use a loop to get the next items (whose url is in `obj._links.next`)