# Trying to Deserialise JSON for .NET from a URL, but getting an error

Tags: c#, json

**I'm trying to use the following code to deserialize a URL:**

```
     private void RefeshList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient list = new WebClient();
            string text = list.DownloadString("http://www.classicube.net/api/serverlist/");
            var server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);
             serverlist.Text = text;

            }
        }
    }

public class RootObject
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public int maxplayers { get; set; }
    public string mppass { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int players { get; set; }
    public int port { get; set; }
    public int uptime { get; set; }

}
```

**But I get an error:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

The URL is: http://www.classicube.net/api/serverlist/

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is- just sayin' :)

Answer (score 5):

It is a json array. Use

```
var server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answers listed, I want to go a step further. If you examine the JSON response returned from the server, you will see:

```
[
    {"hash": "84ce710714eedcdfd7ef22d4776671b0", "maxplayers": 64, "name": "All in the Mined", "players": 0, "uptime": 2107198},
```

The `[` at the very beginning denotes an array in JSON syntax. Many times, one might see JSON objects that contain array properties; however, this is not the case here.  This means that your code needs to ask for an array back (and most serializers appreciate that arrays are IEnumerables, so they are happy with any IEnumerable).

And if you think about it, that makes a lot of sense. You see about 30 of those objects listed in the JSON response- you need an appropriate data structure to contain all the objects returned. A single object is not a match.

So, you need to change your code very slightly, by adding the `List<>` into it. That is the only change required here.

`var server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(text);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `List<RootObject>` to deserialize it properly:

```
List<RootObject> server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(text);
```

Comment: @WWasif Hossain You always do the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020684/get-text-in-string-between-text-in-said-string

Comment: @L.B I would like to clear your confusion that its just overlapping incident. When I saw that no answers have been accepted yet, I tried to answer instantly. I don't know whether matching the answer unintentionally with someone is fault or not.

Comment: And you think it is a good attitude? Instead of posting the same answer, upvote the correct one. (I don't mean a few minutes differences, I say, *after half an hour*.)

Comment: I always try to upvote the appropriate answers and encourage others to do that. Okay, then I would try to read all the answers first and take the next step accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
"hash": "84ce710714eedcdfd7ef22d4776671b0"
"maxplayers": 64
"name": "All in the Mined"
"players": 0
"uptime": 2106398
```

You need set your class like that

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public int maxplayers { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int players { get; set; }
    public int uptime { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is the text returned from the server describes a collection, as evidenced by [].